# Как сделать градиентную полосу обозначающую уровень заполненности?

Tags: html, css, градиент

Нужно сделать градиентную полосу обозначающую уровень заполненности, градиент должен быть горизонтальный, с двумя цветами разными цветами слева и справа, ниже от полосы должны быть значения `0` (слева) и `1 000 000₽` (справа), пример того как это должно выглядеть:

[image]

Цвета:

- Цвет слева: `rgb(223, 89, 80)`
- Цвет справа: `rgb(69, 16, 70)`
- Задний фон: `rgb(18, 18, 18)`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а если изменить вопрос аля "Range input с градиентом" и т.п. то он уже полезен (не смотрел есть уже такие или нет)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setProgress(val){
  $('.progress').css('width', val + '%');
}
setProgress(20)
```

```css
body {background: #333; margin: 100px 25px}
.line {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
}
.progress {
  width: 0;
  height: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #DF5950, #451046);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.points {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.point {
  color: #5F5F5F;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
.min {text-align: left}
.max {text-align: right}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressBar">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="points">
    <div class="point min">0</div>
    <div class="point max">1 000 000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну вы и намудрили со стилями, grid, бесполезные transition и overflow, но выглядит красиво. Кстати, `text-align: left` не нужно было применять, текст по стандарту слева :p

Comment: `grid` - да, можно и по другому, сделал как быстрее;
`overflow` - не обязательно, но желательно, в данном случае это нужно чтобы полоса прогресса не портила скругления;
`transition` - это для красоты, чтобы плавно обновлять прогресс, можно выставить с временем побольше, кстати;
`text-align` - да, не обязательно, но вдруг от родительского элемента в какой-то ситуации унаследует другое значение, я же не знаю контекста вашего кода, поэтому указал явно на всякий случай

Comment: @ΝNL993 Но и Ваше решение тоже не то что бы вау. От флотов можно было бы уже давно отказаться в пользу флексов. Согласен, что тут гриды не нужны, но это решение понять проще, KISS никто не отменял

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит делать прогрессбар, ты потом намучаешься с ним.
Попробуй такой код:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: rgb(18, 18, 18);
        color:white;
    }
    .progress {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        background: white;
    }
    
    .progress .bar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10px;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(223, 89, 80), rgb(69, 16, 70));
    }
    
    .progress .bar .value {
        width: 0%;
        height: 10px;
        background:white;
        float:right;
    }
    
    .min {
        color:gray;
        margin: 3px;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .max {
        margin: 3px;
        color: gray;
        float:right;
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
<div class="progress">
    <div id="bar" class="bar">
        <div id="val" class="value">
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="min">0</div>
<div class="max">1 000 000₽</div> 
<br>
</body>
```

```
<script>
    function progress(val) {
        document.getElementById('val').style.width = (100-val) + "%";
    }
    
    progress(70)
</script>
```

Comment: Наоборот, можно сократить код и будет работать правильно.
В вашем коде `#val` "вытесняет" ширину `#bar`. Если вообще удалить `#val` и в js управлять шириной `#bar` - будет все правильно
https://jsfiddle.net/j70tx6zo/

Comment: @Kliraks , привет, заметьте отличие. bar всегда должен быть 100% чтобы градиент работал правильно. Я имею ввиду, тут градиент фиксированный.

Comment: Если посмотреть на оригинальную картинку то так и сделано.

Comment: соглашусь, тогда можно так: https://jsfiddle.net/j70tx6zo/1/

Comment: Задача выполнена, посмотрим что выберет автор вопроса. И у меня почему-то не открывается этот сайт...

Comment: Возможно кому-то пригодится (если не открывается jsfiddle) https://codepen.io/Kliraks/pen/OJELmyE

Comment: Вау. Кстати, что делает position: relative и position: absolute?

Comment: `position: relative` - точно не помню формулировку, но суть в том, что если не задавать этот параметр, то дочерний элемент с `position: absolute` - будет позиционироваться относительно ближайшего родителя с `position: relative`, либо относительно всей страницы. Соответственно, он нужен для того, чтобы дочерний элемент позиционировать относительно родителя. Как-то так, возможно криво объяснил...)

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз уж все публикуют ответы, то давайте и я свой :)

```css
:root {
  --progress: 55%;
  --left-color: rgb(223, 89, 80);
  --right-color: rgb(69, 16, 70);
  --bg: rgb(18, 18, 18);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#bar, #gradient {
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
}

#bar {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#gradient {
  width: var(--progress);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--left-color), var(--right-color));
}

#bar, #nums {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#nums {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  opacity: .5;
}

#nums > :last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="bar">
    <div></div>
    <div id="gradient"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="nums">
    <span>0</span>
    <span>1 000 000₽</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#x{
display: list-item;
list-style: inside '0';
width: 400px;
height: 1em;
margin-top: 1.3em;
position: relative;
background: rgb(18, 18, 18);
border: .3em solid rgb(18, 18, 18);
border-top: 1.3em solid rgb(18, 18, 18);
color: gray;
}

#x:before{
content: 'магия одного блока';
color: lime;
text-align: center;

background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(223, 89, 80),
rgb(69, 16, 70) 70% 70%, lightgray, lightgray 70% 70%, lightgray);/* !!! */
width: 98%;
height: .5em;
top: -1em;
left: 1%;
z-index: 2;
}
#x:after{
content: '1 000 000';
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
#x:after, #x:before{position: absolute; display: block;}
```

```html
<div id='x'></div>
```